# R: pointer to c function

Tags: c++, r, pointers, rcpp

How to pass a pointer to a function from C code to R (using External R) and after call that function from R??

Something like:

C:

```
typedef void (* FunctionPtr)();
SEXP ans;
PROTECT(ans = /* ?some code? */);
R_tryEval(ans, R_GlobalEnv, NULL);
UNPROTECT(1);
```

R:

```
callback_function()
```

**EDIT:**
@Romain Francois's post was very helpful.
**myapp code:**

```
namespace
{
    void callback()
    {
        std::cout << "callback\n" << std::flush;
    }
}
class Worker
{
public:
/*...*/
    void initialize(argc, argv)
    {
       Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv);

        SEXP ans, val;
        typedef void (* FunctionPtr)();

        PROTECT(ans = Rf_lang2(Rf_install("source"), Rf_mkString("script.R")));
        R_tryEval(ans, R_GlobalEnv, NULL);
        UNPROTECT(1);

        PROTECT(val = Rf_ScalarInteger((int)(&callback)));
        /* pass the address of the pointer to a function */
        PROTECT(ans = Rf_lang2(Rf_install("setCallback"), val));
        R_tryEval(ans, R_GlobalEnv, NULL);
        UNPROTECT(2);
    }
    void uninitialize()
    {
        Rf_endEmbeddedR(0);
    }
};
```

**R and Rcpp**
**script.R**

```
###################
sourceCpp("utils.cpp")
###################
callback <- function()
{
  callCallback()
}
```

**utils.cpp**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

typedef void (* Callback)();
static Callback spCallback = 0;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void callCallback()
{
  if (spCallback) {
    spCallback();
  } else {
    Rprintf("ERROR: callback is not set");
  }
}
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void setCallback(const int address)
{
  spPlaceOrder = (Callback)address;
}
```

Comment: You are not making a lot of sense to me.  Are you simply trying to call a C function from R?

Comment: I'm trying to connect C(C++) code with R. I tried RInside, but it's not suitable in this case.. I'm trying to pass C callback to R and calls that function (callback) from scripts.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at RcppDE where I allow arbitrary C functions to be passed from R down to the Differential Evolution optimization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

External pointers are what you are looking for. They ley you encapsulate pointers to arbitrary data strucures. The word **data** is important here and function pointers are a different beast. If you want to use `C++` and `Rcpp`, what I would suggest is to create a small class that encapsulates the function pointer:

```
typedef void (* FunctionPtr)();
class FunctionPointer {
  FunctionPtr ptr;
public:
    FunctionPointer( FunctionPtr ptr_) : ptr(ptr_){}
} ;
```

and then create an `XPtr<FunctionPointer>`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

// your callback function
void callback(){
    Rprintf( "hello from callback\n" ) ;
}

// The function that creates an external pointer to your 
// callback
// [[Rcpp::export]]
XPtr<FunctionPointer> create_ptr(){
    return XPtr<FunctionPointer>( new FunctionPointer(callback) );
}

// The function that invokes the callback
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void invokeCallback( XPtr<FunctionPointer> callback){
    callback->ptr() ;
}
```

On the R side, you can use lexical scoping for example to wrap the external pointer into an R function:

```
callback <- local( {
    ptr <- create_ptr()
    function(){
        invokeCallback( ptr )
        invisible(NULL)
    } 
} )
callback()
```

Comment: thank you @Romain Francois I'll try it today and post here about results.

Comment: your answer is very closed to my problem; maybe my question wasn't detailed enough... I have a executable file `myapp` which initialize and close R by calling Rf_initEmbeddedR(argc, argv) Rf_endEmbeddedR(0); myapp is something like wrapper around R. I need to pass pointer to a function(callback) from `myapp` to R and call this callback in the scripts... your example shows how to call callbacks from external sources (like dynamic lib)... I hope it's possible to call from `myapp` function declared in R scope and pass fun_ptr as its argument. Thank you!

Comment: fun_ptr should be a part of `myapp`

Comment: I've found solution and will post it later today. Thanks)

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use the `InternalFunction` class in `Rcpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp ;

void callback(){
    Rprintf( "hello from calback\n" ) ;    
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
InternalFunction get_callback(){
    return InternalFunction(callback) ;    
}
```

The implementation is similar to what I described in the other answer. Things on the R side are taken care of by `Rcpp`:

```
callback <- get_callback()
callback()
```

Answer (score 0):

First load the lib:

```
dyn.load("yourDLL.dll")
```

Then use:

> Functions to make calls to compiled code that has been loaded into R.

See [The R FFI](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/lib/R/library/base/html/Foreign.html)

EDIT:

First compile your C-code. On Windows that is the following, but on other OS's similar:

```
gcc mylib.c -shared -o mylib.dll
```

and then in R:

```
dyn.load("mylib.dll")     
tmp1  <- as.raw(rep(0,4))   # 4 bytes to be sent to the function's argument
tmp2<-.C("yourFunctionName", tmp1)   # tmp2 now has the data returned by the func
```

Note that in c++ (not c) the function name has to be the [mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B)

Comment: hi, thanks for a reply. "I'm trying to connect C(C++) code with R. I tried RInside, but it's not suitable in this case.. I'm trying to pass C callback to R and calls that function (callback) from scripts" (comment under the question)

Comment: solution with loading dynamic library is not suitable in this case

Comment: if you dont want to compile your C-code to a DLL then you will have to compile R together with your C-code.

Comment: The answer is a little questionable (essentially: true, but not useful), the follow-up comment is nonsense.

Comment: @Andrii did Dirk's program solve your problem? or should i explain how to do it with a shared library?

Comment: @eznme please give me a small example, maybe your solution is right.. thank you!

Comment: @Andrii did the answer you accepted work? did you try my code?

Comment: hi @eznme, I posted solution in the question.. nope, your answer wasn't right, take a look at comment to Romain Francois post.. actually your solution may work, if this library "mylib.dll" contains static pointer to a function and we load it twice; once in myapp and pass pointer to myapp's callback and once in R to retrieve that pointer (using rcpp, or maybe exsist another solution). Thank you!

Comment: @Andrii That looks a lot more complicated. Personally i will stay with my `.C()` solution because Romain's solution is linking with R directly which makes the gnu-license require me to release my source code.