# Pass a null pointer to C from R using .C

Tags: c, r, ffi

EDIT: No, that thread does not answer my question. See my other edit below.

I am trying to call a function implemented in a C library from R. The signature of the C function is

```
METIS_API(int) METIS_PartGraphKway(idx_t *nvtxs, idx_t *ncon, idx_t *xadj, 
                  idx_t *adjncy, idx_t *vwgt, idx_t *vsize, idx_t *adjwgt, 
                  idx_t *nparts, real_t *tpwgts, real_t *ubvec, idx_t *options, 
                  idx_t *edgecut, idx_t *part);
```

This function allows several of the arguments to be NULL, meaning that the computation will use default values. How can I pass the null pointer as a value from R? My R code looks like this

```
libpath <- '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmetis.so'
dyn.load(libpath)

METIS_PartGraphKway <- function(xadj, adjncy, nparts) {
  nvtxs <- length(xadj) - 1
  ncon <- 1
  .C('METIS_PartGraphKway', as.integer(nvtxs), as.integer(ncon),
    as.integer(xadj), as.integer(adjncy), NULL, NULL, NULL,
    as.integer(nparts), NULL, NULL, NULL, objval=integer(1),
    part=integer(nvtxs))
}

xadj <- 0:4
adjncy <- c(1, 0, 3, 2)
METIS_PartGraphKway(xadj, adjncy, 2)
```

but it gives the error

```
Error in METIS_PartGraphKway(xadj, adjncy, 2) :
  invalid mode (NULL) to pass to C or Fortran (arg 5)
```

I can not find any mention of this in the manual [Writing R extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran). If possible I want to avoid writing a C wrapper to the function and can thus not use the alternative `.Call` foreign function interface.

EDIT: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13904932/379998) suggests to use `as.raw(rep(0, 4))` to create a NULL pointer, but it does not seem to work for me. I no longer get an error, but the behavior of the computation becomes erratic (random and not equal to when called with the same arguments from C) so it does not seem to be a solution. I tried with `as.raw(rep(0, 8))` too, but still no success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: pointer to c function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904786/r-pointer-to-c-function)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904786/r-pointer-to-c-function

Comment: Thanks @alinsoar! See my edit regarding your suggested duplicate. It seems to my like `as.raw` could be a step towards the solution, but I still can't make it work.